# Filter rows from oracle sql table using max value of a column

Tags: sql, oracle, max, inline-view

I am learning oracle SQL, and I have a table like the following:

```
+--------+--------+------------------------+
| name   | nation | count                  |
+--------+--------+------------------------+
| Ruben  | UK     | 2                      |
| Ruben  | EEUU   | 16                     |
| Cesar  | UK     | 21                     |
| Cesar  | EEUU   | 12                     |
| Cesar  | FRANCE | 4                      |
| John   | FRANCE | 3                      |
| John   | UK     | 7                      |
| ....   | ..     | ..                     |
+--------+--------+------------------------+
```

The table above represents an inline view I created with a query. As you can see, the table groups by name and by nation and do some count. I want to filter the table using the count column to have something like this:

```
+--------+--------+
| name   | nation |
+--------+--------+
| Ruben  | EEUU   |
| Cesar  | UK     |
| John   | UK     |
| ....   | ..     |
+--------+--------+
```

As you can see, for each name I want to choose the nation based on the count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `keep` analytic keyword:

```
select name, min(nation) keep (dense_rank last order by cnt)
from (select name, nation, count(*) as cnt
      from /* your data source */
      group by name, nation)
group by name
```

1. `min(nation)` - min is meaningless in this case but you must keep it
   (doesn't work without)
2. `keep` - keeps only one result of `nation`
3. `dense_rank last` says to pick up the last element
4. `order by cnt` says how to define the order of elements

In the end it will make for every name the nation with the biggest count. The same result can be achieved with

```
select name, min(nation) keep (dense_rank first order by cnt desc)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with another level of inner query. Something like:

```
select name, nation
from (
  select name, nation, cnt,
    row_number() over (partition by name, nation order by cnt desc) as rn
  from (
    select name, nation, count(*) as cnt
    from <your table>
  )
)
where rn = 1;
```

The `row_number()` analytic adds a pseudo column to the innermost query that ranks the row with the highest count as 1, for each name/nation; the outermost query then only looks at those ranked first.

You need to decide what to do about ties - if two nation/name rows have the same count, you could show both by using `rank()` instead of `row_number()`; or you could decide which one to choose by adding another column to the `order by` clause. At the moment, if there are two the same, it will only show you one of them - and which it shows is rather arbitrary.